# Null Pointer exception error with spinners int array

Tags: android, arrays, nullpointerexception, spinner

So when I try to set dropdown3 as adapter1, I get a null pointer exception. However I do not get any issues with the String arrays. Why is this happening with the Integer array? What can I do to fix it??

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner dropdown1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnertext1);
    Spinner dropdown2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnertext2);
    Spinner dropdown3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnernumber1);
    String[] items = new String[]{"ml", "oz", "L"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numbers);
        //adapts the string "items" to be an adapter and fit into the spinner.
    dropdown1.setAdapter(adapter);
    dropdown2.setAdapter(adapter);
    dropdown3.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use the same adapter object for two different views.
Try instantiating three different adapters.

Comment: oops ya your right.. I was misreading my log errors I put in the code.. thanks!